# Running existing Ubuntu on new laptop

Tags: boot, dual-boot

A year ago I bought a new SSD to add to my old laptop (Toshiba Satellite L650D) and it worked very fast until the GPU died. I had to buy a new laptop (Acer F5-573G). On the old drive I had Windows 7 and Ubuntu 14.04.05. On the other computer I connected the SSD to the motherboard and systems start like from my laptop so I thought I'd put this into my new laptop.

And there is a problem: I cannot select system and laptop display that there is no device to boot from there.

How can I get both systems to be be visible without installing everything from the beginning?

Comment: Your old install was probably BIOS/MBR and new system is UEFI/gpt. They are not compatible, but you should be able to boot from UEFI, you have to have UEFI Secure boot off to boot in BIOS mode.  If both installs are UEFI then Acer requires a unique setting of "trust".

Comment: Thank you for help. I set in UEFI to can read BIOS and it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some computers are picky about UEFI booting from the internal drive.
My Toshiba Satellite (C55-B) required a system recovery partition first and the EFI partition second. Some Systems require the EFI partition to be fist. Some just take the first FAT partition as the EFI partition.

Look at the partitioning scheme on the HDD that came out of the Acer to see if maybe this is the issue.

Second possible issue is does the Acer use AHCI?

Comment: Thanks for help. I didn't have to checked partitions configuration but I changed only setings in UEFI to read BIOS